# How to create a list of map in FTL(Freemarker)

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a map of list `testMap` and the list inside the `testMap` has a list of maps.

```
testMap = {"list1": list1, "list2" : list2}

list1 = [{"key" : value, "key" : value1},{"key" : value, "key" : value1}]

list2 = [{"key" : value, "key" : value1},{"key" : value, "key" : value1}]
```

I want to separate the testMap into 2 maps testMap1 and testMap2 based on the value of the key in the lists.

This is what I have tried

```
<#assign testMap1 = {}>
<#assign testMap2 = {}>

<#list testMap?keys as key>
    <#assign testMapList = testMap[key]>
    <#assign testList1 = []>
    <#assign testList2 = []>
        <#list testMapList as testList>
            <#if actionMap["key1"]??>
                <#if actionMap["key1"] == "test">
                     <#assign ignore = testList1.add(testList)>
                <#elseif actionMap["key1"] == "test1>
                    <#assign ignore = testList2.add(testList)>
                </#if>
            </#if>
        </#list>

        <#if testList1?has_content>
             <#assign ignore = testMap1.put(key, testList1)>
        <#elseif testList2?has_content>
            <#assign ignore = testMap2.put(key, testList2)>
        </#if>

</#list>
```

But  `<#assign ignore = testList1.add(testList)>` this line throwing an error

> "FreeMarker template error: For ""."" left-hand operand: Expected a
>   hash, but this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper:
>   f.t.SimpleSequence):

I don't know how can I achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The template language is not designed to do such things. You should factor this out into a Java utility, that you call from the template. Or, if this restructuring is meaningful regardless of presentation (formatting), put the data into the data-model already structured like that.

But... if you really must do it inside the template, and `testMap` doesn't have many keys:

```
<#assign testMap1 = {}>
<#assign testMap2 = {}>
<#list testMap as k, v>
  <#assign map1V = v?filter(it -> it.key1 == 1)>
  <#if map1V?size != 0>
    <#assign testMap1 = testMap1 + {k: map1V}>
  </#if>

  <#assign map2V = v?filter(it -> it.key1 != 1)>
  <#if map1V?size != 0>
    <#assign testMap2 = testMap2 + {k: map2V}>
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Reading the resulting two maps will be `O(N)` slow, where N is the number of top-level keys in them. That's why it's important that you don't have many keys there.

As of calling `add`/`put`, it's generally not possible. One workaround is adding an utility that creates a *new* `ArrayList` or `LinkedHashMap`, and then you can use `myList?api.add(...)` and such. There, `?api` allows you to access the Java API. But same won't work on values created with `[]` or `{}`; those aren't mutable collections anyway.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Unknown built-in: "filter"`

Comment: @Santhosh You are using a too old FreeMarker version then.